# facebook not return user data, swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I use `facebook SDK` in `Swift` and I want get user data from `facebook`.

if i try return user data my app crash. If i don't use return app works fine.

```
func getUserDataFromFacebook() -> AnyObject{
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        print(result)

    });

    return result;
}
```

how to return result?

Comment: i have this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0):

i am currently not in front of a mac so this is freehanded code:

Because the Request you do is asynch, you could do something like this to return the object:

```
func getUserDataFromFacebook(completion:(success: Bool, result: AnyObject) -> ()) {
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
    print(result)

    completion(success: (error) ? false : true, result: result)

});
```

}